# Unable to create instance of a resuable view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using this code:

```
import UIKit

class SnackBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let _ = commonInitialization()

    }


    func commonInitialization() -> UIView
    {
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SnackBarView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        return view

    }

}
```

when I try initialising it like this:

```
let snackBar = SnackBarView()
```

it gives the error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call
```

I know there is something wrong in the init function but I am not sure how to correct this. How should I proceed correcting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in your class but rather in how you are attempting to call it.

Since you want to create the `UIView` with zero (0) parameters you need to supply it a constructor (`init`) to deal with that situation when it happens.

Hopefully the below will work to give you a constructor with zero (0) parameters.

```
class SnackBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let _ = commonInitialization()
    }

    // you need to add this init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // call your custom initialization code here
        let _ = commonInitialization()
    }

    // constructor with zero (0) parameters
    convenience init() {
        // call the override from above with a default CGRect
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    func commonInitialization() -> UIView
    {
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SnackBarView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't instantiate the view at all.

Comment: this was to solve the error you were getting with the compile. if the view is not coming up I would debug that code where you are loading from XIB. have you tried to just create a <code>UIView</code> in code without the XIB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `override init(frame: CGRect)` in your view: updated code is below:

```
class SnackBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let _ = commonInitialization()

    }

    // you need to add this init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func commonInitialization() -> UIView
    {
        let bundle = Bundle.init(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SnackBarView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        return view

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's meaningless to create a `UIView` with xib , and then add an instance of the same type to it as `commonInitialization` here occupies all frame of itself , I think you need

```
class SnackBarView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!

    class  func commonInitialization(_ rec:CGRect) -> SnackBarView
    {

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SnackBarView", bundle: nil)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! SnackBarView
        view.frame = rec
        return view

    }

}
```

//

```
let v = SnackBarView.commonInitialization(view.frame)

view.addSubview(v)
```